# Is it good idea to update player stats like this?

Tags: java, encapsulation, updating

I have a simple `Inventory` class going on, that is in charge of managing player Storage and equipped items, but currently I have single method that operates on player himself called `updatePlayer` and I am not sure if it is that good idea, even though it works. So when the player equips armor, for example, this is what happens in the `Inventory` class:

```
public class Inventory {
    private Player playerInstance;
    private Inventory playerInventory;
    public Inventory(Player currentPlayer) {
        playerInstance = currentPlayer;
        playerInventory = currentPlayer.getInventory();
    }

    /*This is a snippet of equipArmor method(to actually choose the armor to equip,
      there are other pieces of code too, but I ommited them to keep it short):*/
    public void equipArmor() {
        playerInstance.setArmorValue(armorToEquip.getArmorStat());
        playerInventory.removeItem(amorToEquip.getID());
    }

    /*And this is the method I am talking about,
      it is basically my cleaner after all operations on inventory have been performed:*/
    public Player updatePlayer(){
        return playerInstance;
    }
}
```

And this is how I handle the stat change to the real player instance inside the main method:

```
Inventory inv = new Inventory(currentPlayer);
inv.equipArmor();
currentPlayer = inv.updatePlayer();
currentPlayer.setInventory(inv.updateInventory());
```

Is this system okay, or should I try to refactor to something else?

Comment: What does Inventory represent? Something the Player carries with him?  And why does Inventory have an Inventory field? I'm confused.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Inventory is bag of belongings the player has and yes, he carries it with him at all times. Every Player entity that is created has its own Inventory and I added the field so that the Inventory can work on Player inventory instance that was passed as constructor parameter in particular.

Comment: Why does an Inventory care about what player it belongs to?  A Player having an Inventory makes sense, but not the other way around.  If you want to modify a Player, run a method on the Player, and it's up to the Player class how to implement that (such as forwarding a call to its Inventory).

Comment: `"I added the field so that the Inventory can work on Player inventory instance that was passed as constructor parameter in particular."` -- the instances should be one and the same, no? There's no need for that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good thing to ask yourself is "does this model in the real world?". If you are going to use composition, you may ask yourself the question, "does an `Inventory` have a `Player`?".

The answer here is no, A `Player` is much more likely to have an `Inventory`, so following that logic you can say:

```
class Player {
    Inventory inventory;

    void equipArmor(Armor armor) {
        inventory.addArmor(armor);
    }
}

class Inventory {
    Armor armor;

    void addArmor(Armor armor) {
        this.armor = armor;
    }
}
```

And this is how you would use it:

```
LootChest chest = Game.getLootChest(); // i'm making these up
Armor armor = chest.getArmor();

Player player = Game.getCurrentPlayer();
if (armor != null && player.accepts()) {
    player.equipArmor(armor);
}
```

Note that most of this is made up, but I used it to demonstrate an OO concept

Answer (score 0):

I think a better design would be to let the Player know about his inventory, but not the Inventory to know the Player. Because a Player has-a Inventory but a Inventory does not have-a Player.

```
public class Player  {
    private final Inventory inventory = new Inventory();

    public void updateInventory() {
        // Update the inventory on the screen here (sync to the player).
    }

    /* Other stuff */
}

public class Inventory {
    // Contents and stuff ...

    public void add(/* Any Item */) { ... }

    public void removeArmor(/* Any Item */) { ... }

    /* Other stuff */
}
```

With this solution, you do not have any dependency-cycle

```
+---> Player -----+
|                 |
+--- Inventory <--+
```

How you could use it:

```
Player player = ...;
player.equipArmor();
player.getInventory().removeArmor();
player.updateInventory();
```

You can also auto-update the inventory, but I think you do not want to do that (performance).

Comment: My logic was not that Inventory has Player, but that Inventory manages itself without needing Player assistence and operates on Players inventory. Player should only give simple commands while Inventory handles the logic and then request the update. But your idea is actually better.